# Disable Switchery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, switchery

i want to disable switchery but failed i did try difrent code from [here](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) this code doesn't work for me

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-dynamic-state');
var switchery = new Switchery(elem);

document.querySelector('.js-dynamic-disable').addEventListener('click', function() {
  switchery.disable();
});

document.querySelector('.js-dynamic-enable').addEventListener('click', function() {
  switchery.enable();
});
```

on creating new switchry it can be set disable but in other event it doesn't work `switchery.disable();` it displays error in console

> disable is not function

i also did try this which generates new switchery

```
var switchery = new Switchery(elem, { disabled: true });
```

when i use the above given code completely in that event it generates new switchery button.

any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
var init = new Switchery(elem);
init.disable();
init.enable();
```

Use the above code to disable() function the  disable the element. or enable() function to enable the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/63kamhss/1/

Comment: without new keyword ?

Comment: @ahok var init = new Switchery(elem); this line generates the new button but i want to disable existing switchery.

Comment: @ ashok, i was referencing the old file of swithchery.js i just referenced thew new one and disable function is now working properly. thanks for your help.